# Alamofire error when creating Stripe customer ID (iOS)

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, alamofire, stripe-payments

I am using Alamofire and Swift in my Heroku app using Node.js (integrating Stripe). However, when creating a customer ID, I get the following error. My code sets are below.

Let me know if any other details are required to know.

> Error message: 
>   Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)

**Client side code**

```
func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String, completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {

    let customerIDURL = self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("customer")
    let customerIDParameters = ["email":(Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)!]

    Alamofire.request(customerIDURL, method: .post, parameters: customerIDParameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).validate(statusCode: 200..<300).responseJSON { responseJSON in

        switch responseJSON.result {
            case .success(let json):
                completion(json as? [String:AnyObject], nil)
                print("\(json)\n\n\n\n")
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(nil, error)
                print("Error message:\(responseJSON.result.error)")
                break
        }
    }
```

**Server side code**

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

var app = express();
var stripe = require('stripe')('secret_key')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));

app.post('/customer', (req, res) => {

  var email = req.body.email;

  stripe.customers.create({
    email: email
  }, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, req.body)
      res.status(500).end()
    } else {
      res.status(200).send()
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you check with POSTMAN, but I think that your response is no data in your response (nil or empty), just a 200 status code, so there is no response to parse, and you get that error.

Comment: @Larme How would I add the data to the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means that Alamofire is failing when processing the response JSON.

Specifically, the issue seems to be on the server side - as far as I can tell you are not sending a valid JSON response back from the server, just a status code of 200.

To send back data you'll need to supply a parameter to res.send(), for example:

```
res.status(200).send({'email':email})
```

Also, the [Stripe API docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_customer) state that the callback function receives two parameters, the second being the customer object. So the code could be implemented as such:

```
stripe.customers.create({
  email: email
}, function(err, customer) {
  if (err) {
    res.status(500).end()
  } else {
    res.status(200).send(customer)
  }
}
```